# Awk not printing the whole line

Tags: awk, sh

I am executing the following script using awk which prints the columns of a file in a different order.

```
#!/bin/sh

cat test.txt | awk  '{ if ($3 != "") {print $3 "  " $1 "  " $2} else if (($3 == "") && ($2 != "")) {print $2 "  " $1 } }' > test_proc.txt
```

My expectation of output from: print $3 "  " $1 "  " $2

```
$3  $1  $2
$3  $1  $2
```

What is actually printed from: print $3 "  " $1 "  " $2

```
$3
  $1  $2
$3
  $1 $2
```

Similary, my expectation of output from: print $2 "  " $1

```
$2  $1
$2  $1
```

What is actually printed from: print $2 "  " $1

```
$2
  $1
$2
  $1
```

Here are some lines from test.txt:

```
rd-abc 0000002000000000
0x47FF93A0 rd-abc  DFFDC08C02020000
```

Why do I get an unexpected carriage return in between?

Comment: Because the input file contains a carriage return?

Comment: Check Input_file by doing `cat -v Input_file` if they have carriage characters and see if control M characters are there.

Comment: @ triplee - Thanks. I did not realize that I need to explicitly delete carriage return from the whole file. That works then for me

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - thanks. I don't see any character being highlighted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following to remove the carriage returns from your Input_file:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks. Replacing all carriage returns in the file did the trick: sed -e 's/\r//g'

Comment: Just to be expand it a bit : unix files terminate lines with `\n` while dos files with `\r\n`. As `awk` is looking for `\n` only, the `\r` is still part of `$3`, hence the weird output. The tool `dos2unix` should fix the problem or the line in this answer.